# TeamCity is taking forever to start

Tags: windows, teamcity

TeamCity has been hanging for for a long time (over 3 hours), is there anyway to restart team city as I wonder if there is some file locked somewhere.

[image: TeamCity is starting]

Answer (score 0):

Go into Services (Start -> Run -> Services.msc) and restart the TeamCity service. I had this happen to me yesterday and I had to stop the Teamcity process from Task Manager before I could start the Service.

Comment: TeamCity failed to stop, didn't respond to request from the server.

Comment: You'll have to do as I pointed out in the latter part of my answer and manually kill (via Task Manager) the TeamCity process.

Comment: Apologioes it looks like our DB server is hosed at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 things you need to do.

First you need to figure out where the process is stuck at. You can find this wherever your teamcity "server logs are located".

Next, you can either fix/ignore that issue and restart your process. Usualy its due to issues like disk space, db errors etc but the server logs do mention it explicitly